# Is it technically possible to use the result of a recursive CTE as a subquery inside parentheses ? (in MySql)

Tags: mysql, subquery, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Such as this :

```
Select * From (
     WITH RECURSIVE cte_name AS (
              initial_query  -- anchor member
             UNION ALL
             recursive_query -- recursive member that references to the CTE name
        )
    SELECT * FROM cte_name
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

Section 13.2.13 of the MySql 8.0 reference manual that handles [WITH syntax for Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), mentions the following :

> A WITH clause is permitted in these contexts: 
>   At the beginning of subqueries (including derived table subqueries):
>
> ```
> SELECT ... WHERE id IN (WITH ... SELECT ...) ...
> SELECT * FROM (WITH ... SELECT ...) AS dt ...
> ```

So, that clarifies my question, therefore putting my own answer as a community wiki.